¿Puedo obtener las coordenadas de un punto de un mapa en folium haciendo click?
Estoy haciendo una página con streamlit y dentro uso un mapa, me gustaría que los puntos pudieran ser seleccionados a partir de click y obtener las coordenadas. No sé si sea posible.
